# Private fields and methods for a struct

Tags: go

In the following test code I would like to have both `mytype` and the `doPrivate` method private, so that only members of `mytype` can access it, but not other types\functions in the scope of the `mypackage` package.

Can I do this in golang?

```
package mypackage

type mytype struct {
    size          string
    hash          uint32
}

func (r *mytype) doPrivate() string {
    return r.size
}

func (r *mytype) Do() string {
    return doPrivate("dsdsd")
}
```

Fields `size` and `hash` as well as the `doPrivate` method should be encapsulated and no other type should have access to them.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

That's not how "privacy" works in Go: the granularity of privacy is the package.

If you *really* want only the members of `mytype` to access some fields, then you must isolate the struct and the functions in their own package.

But that's not the usual practice. Whether Go is OOP or not is debatable but clearly the practice isn't to encapsulate the code by a struct like you seem to want to do. Usually a package is small enough to be coherent: if you don't want to access fields from within the package, don't access them.

Comment: I'd suggest you to read the code of some major standard packages of Go. Yes, whole packages. You'll be amazed at the clarity and simplicity this choice allows. Don't try to emulate another language in Go.

Comment: good point, I don't like nor understand why people emulate "classes" or "classical inheritance" in JavaScript. In this point of time, it seems wired.

Comment: one remark though, the sentence "if you don't want to access fields from within the package, don't access them" - you could say that about encapsulation in general, but that doesn't solve any problems. It seems that Golang moves abstraction from class-scope to a package-scope. In my opinion it may make programs difficult to maintain. Just like modules in JavaScript (except for private fields).

Comment: The implicit reasoning behind is that the package is simple and small enough so that there's no coherency problem and no need of inner privacy enforcing. If you feel it makes it harder to maintain, maybe your package is too big. Of course, we're here rather in the domain of opinions and different programmer practices and experiences.

Comment: I get your point. +1 for "package is simple and small enough" and "domain of opinions". For now I must assume a Google's better reasoning than mine :) I can't wait to implement first micro-service in Golang :)

Comment: Until they came along with `strict private` a few versions back, it was always the same way in Delphi: Even members marked `private` were in scope to an entire unit. That did not mean it was not OOP,  like `friend` classes in C++ don't mean it's not OOP. It just means you only keep "friends" in your packages if you want to maintain encapsulation. After years of working with Delphi and C++, I **love** the simplicity of Go's package/`init()` approach. Between that and automated garbage collection, you eliminate 30 or 40% of the functionally useless code you're forced to write in other languages.

Comment: I like this statement "Usually a package is small enough to be coherent: if you don't want to access fields from within the package, don't access them.". I think there must be a point where programmers stop treating themselves as a stupid person.

Comment: Such a thing should be part of the language. Software Design and developers who will join the team later would be thankful, they do not have to handle with a Lava Flow, Duplicated, Giant Ball of Mud Monolith Application

Comment: @Spektakulatius Let them reinvent it at some time in the future with the proud look of pioneers.

Comment: "package is simple and small enough" sounds like a decent design paradigma until you pair it with the constraint of acyclic dependency graphs, and start drawing trees on paper and spending minutes to hours thinking of how you want to build your hierarchy of types so that you have everthing you need without code duplication. I honestly do not undersand the popularity of go.

Answer (score 121):

In Go, an identifier that starts with a capital letter is exported from the package, and can be accessed by anyone outside the package that declares it.

If an identifier starts with a lower case letter, it can only be accessed from within the package.

If you need members in a type to only be accessed by members of that type, you then need to place that type and its member functions in a separate package, as the only type in that package.

Answer (score 44):

You can create an interface with the method you wish to expose and only access the object when wrapped into that interface.

```
package main

type mytype struct {
    size string
    hash uint32
}

// interface for exposed methods
type myinterface interface {
    do() string
}

// constructor (optional)
func newMytype(size string, hash uint32) myinterface {
    return &mytype{size, hash}
}

func (r *mytype) doPrivate() string {
    return r.size
}

func (r *mytype) do() string {
    return r.doPrivate()
}

func main() {
    // with constructor
    t := newMytype("100", 100)
    t.do()
    // t.doPrivate() // t.doPrivate undefined (type myinterface has no field or method doPrivate)

    // without constructor
    t2:= myinterface(&mytype{"100", 100})
    t2.do()
    // t.doPrivate() // t.doPrivate undefined (type myinterface has no field or method doPrivate)doPrivate)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/awjIIj8Kwms

Comment: Out of all the answers this one combines the best of all worlds and should be higher up. Proper programming indeed involves interfaces so all the more reason to employ them. Nicely done!

Comment: This is exactly what I do in my code.

Comment: This is definitely the best answer.

Answer (score 14):

You cannot do this in Go. Visibility is on a per package level only. But you may split your package into two.

Answer (score 7):

In one module there can be any number of packages.

Public/Private works only across one package.
All **public** fields, methods and functions starts with **uppercase** char.
All **private** fields, methods and functions starts with **lowercase** char.

To add package to your module or program just create a lowercase folder and add package name to all files inside. Here is the example.

```
./main.go
./foo/foo.go
./foo/MyStruct.go
```

file `./foo/foo.go`:

```golang
package foo

import "fmt"

func SomePublicFuncInFoo() {
    somePrivateFuncInFoo()
}

func somePrivateFuncInFoo() {
    fmt.Println("somePrivateFuncInFoo call")
}
```

file `./foo/MyStruct.go`:

```golang
package foo

import "fmt"

type MyStruct struct {
    MyPublicField  string // starts with uppercase char
    myPrivateField string // starts with lowercase char
}

func NewMyStruct(publicField string, privateField string) *MyStruct {
    return &MyStruct{
        MyPublicField:  publicField,  
        myPrivateField: privateField, 
    }
}

func (self *MyStruct) SomePublicMethod() {
    self.privateMethod()
}

func (self *MyStruct) privateMethod() {
    fmt.Println("MyStruct", self.MyPublicField, self.myPrivateField)
}
```

file `./main.go`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "{your-module-name}/foo" // this line should be added by your IDE
)

func main() {

    foo.SomePublicFuncInFoo()

    myStruct := foo.NewMyStruct("string1", "string2")
    fmt.Println("myStruct.MyPublicField=", myStruct.MyPublicField)

    myStruct.SomePublicMethod()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have private variables and functions in Go, but the trick is that you simply don't define them in the struct. Bind them to the call stack of a  closure, and simply don't return them.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type mytype struct {
    Do func() string
}

func MyType(size string, hash uint32) mytype {
    doPrivate := func() string {
        return size
    }
    return mytype{
        Do: func() string {
            return doPrivate()
        },
    }
}

func main() {
    instance := MyType("100", 100)
    fmt.Println(instance.Do())
}
```