# Accessing a strut from another package

Tags: go

I have the following modules

```golang
package apack

type Something structs{
    a string
    b string
}

var FullList []Something

func Complete() []Something {
    FullList = append(FullList, Something{
                      a: 'first',
                      b: 'second'
               })
    return FullList
}
```

Now the following main

```golang
import "something/apack"

func main() {
    re = apack.Complete()
    for _,s := range re {
        s1 := apack.Something(s)
        fmt.Println(s1)
    }
}
```

when I run it I get the following:

```bash
{first second}
```

but if I do something like

```golang
        fmt.Println(s1.a)
```

I get the following error:

```bash
./main.go:70:19: s1.a undefined (type apack.Something has no field or method a)
```

Is it possible to be able to access structs from another package?

I think `map` should work, just unsure how for this case.

Thanks

Comment: Please see [the tour](https://go.dev/tour/basics/3) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22148240/11810946) (if the field name is not capitalised then it's not available outside the package).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible, just make the fields of your struct (that you want to access from the other package) exported:

```
type Something struct {
    A string
    b string
}
```

Then you can access all the exported fields from the struct so `fmt.Println(s1.A)` in the other package code will now work, but `fmt.Println(s1.b)` will not work as `b` is still an unexported field.

Also, [here](https://go.dev/tour/basics/3) is a very simple lesson from [A Tour of Go](https://go.dev/tour/list) (which I also recommend as a whole) about exported names.